# Drag n'Drop to NotifyIcon

Tags: vb.net, notifyicon

Is there any way to drag and drop files into a NotifyIcon using .NET and Visual STudio 2013? Is there any "extender" to add the Drag-Drop events to NotifyIcon?

Thanks!